# Android how simple remove list item from listview?

Tags: android, android-listview

i have a list of folder in directory, on onListItemClick event calling show alert dialog and after click on yes button i processing delete of the file. I would like after successful delete of the file also remove selected item from list or refresh view with new values.

How can i do it most simple?

Code of Package activity:

```
public class PackageListActivity extends ListActivity
{
    // create instance of App helper class
    AppHelper helper = new AppHelper();
    String folderNameToDelete;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // get arrayListOf folders
        ArrayList<String> folderArrayList =  helper.getListOfFileInDirectory(null);
        // convert array listo to simple array
        String[] arr = folderArrayList.toArray(new String[folderArrayList.size()]);
        // set to aray adapter
        setListAdapter(new PackageArrayAdapter(this, arr));
    }


    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        //get selected items
        String selectedValue = (String) getListAdapter().getItem(position);
        //Toast.makeText(this, selectedValue, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        this.showAlerDialog(selectedValue);
    }
```

Comment: Just remove the item from `folderArrayList` and then use `notifyDatasetChanged()` to update the `ListView`.

Answer (score 0):

remove the arraylist item by giving the position to be removed and then call notifyDataSetChanged() method by using your adapter

```
folderArrayList.remove(<index of element to remove>);
PackageArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```